# Parse JSON file using PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, file, parsing

I have a JSON that I need to parse.

```
{
    "Room 251": {
        "calID": "igm4pfi6cc78ncvm5i3gv521snp0si82@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Open Computer Lab"
        },

    "Room 318": {
        "calID": "9duielvutvv2b8d52ikgf8793pbn43sk@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Open Computer Lab"
        },

    "Room 319 (Friends Room)": {
        "calID": "q5tj99a61g71eqcaboae6md0qahle2hv@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Available For Study"
        },

    "Room 323": {
        "calID": "josiglibstb75c88o4s4f2r3h4i3lagc@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Open Computer Lab"
        },

    "Room 513 (Voinovich Room)": {
        "calID": "anjv4nfcr0b00sttbjp6cse5l7j0mvbe@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Available For Study"
        }
}
```

I need to obtain the room name, the calID, and the available message. What would be the best way to go about doing this in PHP/Laravel?

Comment: have you ever tried some thing to do this ?

Comment: Meaning what exactly?

Comment: have you tried any thing to parse json using laravel or php ?

Comment: json_decode() in PHP but I didn't know if there was a Laravel specific way of going about doing it.

Comment: Laravel is built on PHP - same thing. Once you've got the data in your controller, you use PHP to get the data and manipulate it the same way you would in any other PHP bit.

Comment: `$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);` returns a multidimensional array. Any laravel specific way would be pointless as it would be an abstraction of this one liner

Comment: There is no Laravel specific way of decoding a json object other than using the PHP's built-in function `json_decode`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `json_decode` to parse a json data.

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc ] )

For example:

```
$rooms = json_decode($yourJsonHere, true);

var_dump($rooms);

foreach($rooms as $name => $data) {
    var_dump($name, $data['calID'], $data['availMsg']); // $name is the Name of Room
}
```

Comment: That gives all of the rooms as a multidimensional array, which I already have. I need to get the values from the rooms and set them to variables

Comment: Why set them to variables? Why can't you use array?

Comment: Because I need them to be variables to pass later on.

Comment: Okay, do as you wish.

Comment: Marked yours as correct as it had the correct solution to what I was needing even though i didn't need the data set into an array. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

```
<?php
$json = '
{
    "Room 251": {
        "calID": "igm4pfi6cc78ncvm5i3gv521snp0si82@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Open Computer Lab"
        },

    "Room 318": {
        "calID": "9duielvutvv2b8d52ikgf8793pbn43sk@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Open Computer Lab"
        },

    "Room 319 (Friends Room)": {
        "calID": "q5tj99a61g71eqcaboae6md0qahle2hv@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Available For Study"
        },

    "Room 323": {
        "calID": "josiglibstb75c88o4s4f2r3h4i3lagc@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Open Computer Lab"
        },

    "Room 513 (Voinovich Room)": {
        "calID": "anjv4nfcr0b00sttbjp6cse5l7j0mvbe@import.calendar.google.com",
        "availMsg": "Available For Study"
        }
}';
foreach(json_decode($json) as $room_name => $room){
  echo $room_name.'<br/>'; // output the room name, for instead "Room 251"
  echo $room->calID.'<br/>'; // output the room calID
  echo $room->availMsg.'<br/>'; // output the room availMsg
}

 ?>
```

Comment: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: I've tested it, it works, are you sure you don't miss something while copy/paste it ?

Comment: `$cal_ID = $keys['calID'];

            $availMsg = $keys['availMsg'];

           echo $cal_ID;
           echo "<br>";
           echo $availMsg;
           echo "<br>";`

Comment: don't you think that `$data = json_decode($json); foreach ($data .....` would be better ? @VincentG

Comment: Maybe it could be better in performance term, but I'm not sure. It provides the same output result though.